# Precision loss / rounding difference when directly assigning double result to an int

Tags: c, math, casting, double, precision

Is there a reason why converting from a double to an int performs as expected in this case:

```
double value = 45.33;
double multResult = (double) value*100.0; // assign to double
int convert = multResult;                 // assign to int
printf("convert = %d\n", convert);        // prints 4533 as expected
```

But not in this case:

```
double value = 45.33;
int multResultInt = (double) value*100.0;      // assign directly to int
printf("multResultInt = %d\n", multResultInt); // prints 4532??
```

It seems to me there should be no difference. In the second case the result is still first stored as a double before being converted to an int unless I am not understanding some difference between casts and hard assignments.

Comment: Just to mention, `(double)` cast is redundant.

Comment: For me both are the same, which compiler do you use? (http://ideone.com/arImWb)

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you remove the `(double)` casts? In both cases, the cast applies only to `value`, which is already of type `double`. (The spacing is misleading; the cast binds more tightly than the `*` operator.)

Comment: Compiler version: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed no difference between the two, but compilers are used to take some freedom when it comes down to floating point computations. For example compilers are free to use **higher** precision for intermediate results of computations but higher still means different so the results may vary.

Some compilers provide switches to always drop extra precision and convert all intermediate results to the prescribed floating point numbers (say 64bit double-precision numbers). This will make the code slower, however.

In the specific the number `45.33` cannot be represented exactly with a floating point value (it's a periodic number when expressed in binary and it would require an infinite number of bits). When multiplying by `100` this value **may be** you don't get an integer, but something very close (just below or just above).

`int` conversion or cast is performed using truncation and something very close to `4533` but below will become `4532`, when above will become `4533`; even if the difference is incredibly tiny, say `1E-300`.

To avoid having problems be sure to account for numeric accuracy problems. If you are doing a computation that depends on **exact values** of floating point numbers then you're using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1):

@6502 has given you the theory, here's how to look at things experimentally

```
double v = 45.33;
int x = v * 100.0;
printf("x=%d v=%.20lf v100=%.20lf\n", x, v, v * 100.0 );
```

On my machine, this prints

```
x=4533 v=45.32999999999999829470 v100=4533.00000000000000000000
```

The value `45.33` does not have an exact representation when encoded as a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number. The actual value of `v` is slightly lower than the intended value due to the limited precision of the encoding.

So why does multiplying by `100.0` fix the problem on some machines? One possibility is that the multiplication is done with 80-bits of precision and then rounded to fit into a 64-bit result.  The 80-bit number `4532.999...` will round to `4533` when converted to 64-bits.

On your machine, the multiplication is evidently done with 64-bits of precision, and I would expect that `v100` will print as `4532.999...`.